# What are Mercenary Commendations?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

One of the PvP vendors in the Imperial Fleet accepts both Warzone Commendations, that you get for participating in warzone matches, and Mercenary Commendations.

What are those Mercenary Commendations? How do you get them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are no longer obtainable, but used to be awarded for World PvP and Ilum. They could also be found in chests in the PvP area Outlaw's Den on Tatooine. You can trade them in at the PvP vendor: 30 Mercenary for 10 Warzone comms.

Comment: Ok, how do I take part in World PvP? Or is it too a level 50 thing (like Ilum, I assume)?

Comment: @svick Just turn up at Outlaw's Den on Tatooine, it's south of Outpost Salara and north of Mos Anek in Jundland. There's no entry requirements (your class quests will probably bring you into the area at around level 25) and it's not instanced, the entrance to the valley housing Outlaw's Den is surrounded by flags warning that entering the area automatically flags you for PvP, and anyone (even those on your own faction) can attack you(r group).